# Set up emacs LSP to also work with standalone files and scripts

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp

I'm pretty new to emacs, and I wanted to setup an LSP with code completion for java and other languages there.
I started out with java and made a simple configuration

```lisp
(use-package lsp-mode
 :hook (java-mode . lsp-deferred)
 :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
 :config (lsp-enable-which-key-integration t))
(use-package lsp-java
   :config (add-hook 'java-mode-hook #'lsp))
```

but I also want LSP for any other standalone files and scripts, which I somehow cannot get to work. Whenever I open a standalone `.java` file I get this prompt:

```
test.java is not part of any project.

i ==> Import project root /home/maksatr/Documents/
I ==> Import project by selecting root directory interactively
. ==> Import project at current directory /home/maksatr/Documents/
d ==> Do not ask again for the current project by adding /home/maksatr/Documents/ to lsp-session-folders-blocklist
D ==> Do not ask again for the current project by selecting ignore path interactively
n ==> Do nothing: ask again when opening other files from the current project

Select action:
```

and as you can see every option is either creating a project or bypassing it without having all of the LSP's benefits.
Googling the issue seems to miss it, perhaps because it's a pretty noob question that I just failed to solve properly.
I have also tried Eglot, but it does not seem to show good enough completions, only syntax errors.
Is there a way to set it up in a way so that it also works with standalone files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, thankfully it was rather simple:

```lisp
(use-package lsp-mode
 :hook (java-mode . lsp-deferred)
 :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
 :config 
(setq lsp-auto-guess-root t) ; This is the fix
(lsp-enable-which-key-integration t))
(use-package lsp-java
   :config (add-hook 'java-mode-hook #'lsp))
```